# Unable to us GCM In my Country

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have special problem and I gave up thinking and got confused.

I have an application that gives notifications using GCM and I am using "ONE SIGNAL" for notes because it was recommended and easy, and I
succeed in it and could give notes.

The problem is that I'm living in Iran and because of Sanctions I need a VPN to use one signal. When the app starts it want to login to "ONE SIGNAL" server (with APP key and Api key) - without VPN the app will hang up but with the VPN on the app will work correctly and will login.

I was thinking that for solving it but i could turn on VPN program in app and login , after it turn VPN off, but its not good.

Now I don't know what to do, both GCM - ONE SIGNAL am unable to use....

Please tell me how to use them or at least how to send notification?

Comment: There is also an Iranian service here http://pushe.co which provides a simple graphical interface for developers to send push notifications using GCM, and it also is intended to work in Iran ! You might want to give that a try also.

Comment: u just did a greaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat job , thanks man thanks , i really thank you!

Comment: You can use [cheshmak.me](https://cheshmak.me), It works with lower versions of google play services and doesn't require login to google. It provides good services in Iran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue is that the app is failing to receive a GCM push notification token. The token creation process requires the device to interact with Google's GCM servers, and these may be blocked in Iran. Unfortunately there's no workaround I can think of other than using a VPN like you already are.